# Chrome (OS) extension to open a terminal and run commands to switch boot partitions

Tags: scripting, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, google-chrome-os

I am one of the few lucky people that received a Google CR-48 to test Chrome OS. I love Chrome OS, and use it for nearly all of my leisure browsing but when I need to program I like to use linux. To switch from Chrome OS to linux I do the following:

```
ctrl + alt + ->                         -- open terminal
$ chronos                               -- log in as chronos user
$ sudo su                               -- gain privileges
$ sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/sda -- switch boot partition
```

While issuing these commands doesn't take a lot of time, I feel like I could automate it somehow. Does the Chrome extension API have access to the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Chrome extensions are just code fed to the browser for execution. The browser has no access to the terminal, there is no API for it, experimental or otherwise.

Sources: [Chrome extension APIs index](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html)